# Is this set a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

[image]

*I think the identity and inverse properties are true.*

Comment: I fail to see what you're confused about. You need to show whether this satisfies the group axioms or not, and your last comment indicates that you already know this. What is specifically giving you trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a group. Writing $H_a = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a\\0 & 1-a \end{pmatrix}$

1. it is closed since $a\ne 1$ and $b \ne 1 \implies H_a H_b \in H$ since $a+b-ab=1 \implies a=1$ or $b=1$
2. Matrix multiplication is associative
3. the identity is $H_0=I$
4. the inverse is $H_{a/(a-1)}$